# Histogram fill with logarithmic scale

Tags: pgfplots

I face a "filling" problem when I run one of the pgfplots example but with y-log scale. Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogyaxis}[ymin=0,ymax=1,enlargelimits=false]
    \addplot
      [const plot,fill=blue,draw=black]
      coordinates
        {(0,0.1)    (0.1,0.15)  (0.2,0.5)   (0.3,0.62)
         (0.4,0.56) (0.5,0.58)  (0.6,0.65)  (0.7,0.6)
         (0.8,0.58) (0.9,0.55)  (1,0.52)}
  \closedcycle;
  \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output result

[image: Here is the result]

I also try to change the minimal value of y since logarithm of 0.0 is undefined but it does not help.

Comment: Logarithmic bar plots are a Bad Idea: The zero point on a logarithmic plot is arbitrary, which defeats the whole idea of representing quantities using lengths. There's a nice discussion of this on http://bzintelguru.com/blog/bar-chart-with-a-log-axis-never-says-the-biz-intel-guru/. A simple line plot is often more appropriate.

Comment: @Jake I saw your answer in another topic. I get the point raised in the link but it really depends on what you want to see and to emphasize. In high energy particle physics, it is quite usual to show both the linear and logarithmic scale especially for low probability event.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting! Would you happen to have a reference to a paper at hand where a logarithmic bar chart is used, by any chance?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.3716 but maybe this is what you call a simple line plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the origin for logarithmic plots to always be at the bottom edge of the plot, by using `log origin y=infty`. This will affect the path drawn by `\closedcycle`, and define where plot styles like `ybar` and `ycomb` start. By default, the origin is set to `log origin y=0`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogyaxis}[
    ymin=0.05,
    ymax=1,
    log origin=infty,
    enlargelimits=false
  ]
    \addplot
      [const plot,fill=blue,draw=black]
      coordinates
        {(0,0.1)    (0.1,0.15)  (0.2,0.5)   (0.3,0.62)
         (0.4,0.56) (0.5,0.58)  (0.6,0.65)  (0.7,0.6)
         (0.8,0.58) (0.9,0.55)  (1,0.52)}
  \closedcycle;
  \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```